# Windows Hosts file Entry for Dev Server

Tags: networking, windows-8, google-chrome, dns, hosts-file

I have an ip address that I don't want to assign to my domain just yet while it is being developed. However I would like a way for my clients to access the site other than typing in the address. I looked into making changes to the clients' host files and am trying it on my (Wind 8) PC. However the name is not resolving and chrome is returning a not found error.

If ultimately what I want is not possible, do I have any other options like this to create a text shortcut to an ip address?

I found the concept here under creating shortcuts:

http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/6-surprising-uses-for-the-windows-hosts-file/

Here is my hosts file, what am I doing wrong?

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host
    XXX.XX.XXX  app-dev     # app dev server

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
```

In the browser I type in:
    app-dev/

And chrome returns a not found error.

Comment: First up check if you can resolve the name from a command prompt. You want to make sure there is no network issue preventing communication. 


Can you ping the server via the name or IP? If pinging by the name doesn't work then try the IP address.


If you can resolve via the  name then you might need to check if the app-dev server is listening on the default port (eg. port 80) or some other port and include that in your connection. 


If it works from the command prompt then it would suggest an issue in your browser config (e.g proxy configuration)

Comment: I can ping and access the ip from the command prompt and browser respectively. However the browser (tried chrome and firefox) and pinging from the command prompt do not work with the name.

Comment: just a wild guess, but try adding a `.com` or `.net` or something to the `app-dev`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the system is not joined to your domain, you will likely have to use WINS to reach the server by name only.  If you want to see what your computer thinks is at that address, then use the command

```
PING -A xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

where, of course, the X's are for the IP address.

Then you will see the fully-qualified name of the machine as your system sees it, and should be able to reach it by that name.

You might try putting the name into LMHOSTS instead of HOStS, and just make sure that you enable NETBIOS in the advanced settings for TCP/IP - IPV4. Adapter settings → properties → TCP/IP v4 → Properties → Advanced button → WINS tab : select "enable LMHOSTS lookup" and "Default".

Essentially, the DNS lookup is failing because it's not in your domain, so you use LMHOSTS + WINS to give your system a way to find it.

Comment: Great work. Thank you very much! The LMHOSTS file was what I needed to be writing in.